# Is my server still vulnerable to Shell Shock?

Tags: linux, security, debian, shellshock

I updated my Debian server since Shell Shock vulnerability was known.

Before update, I had:

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
vulnerable
this is a test
```

Now, I have:

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
this is a test
```

As I expected to obtain:

```
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
this is a test
```

I wonder if the update really corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are patched for time being. There are some more upcoming things on Bash which will be fixed next time.

However, Debian is in default settings not as much effected as other distributions as /bin/sh is linking to Dash on Debian and not to Bash as on most others.

Answer (score 0):

According to stalwarts like [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/09/bug-in-bash-shell-creates-big-security-hole-on-anything-with-nix-in-it/) you are patched.